# Citations for Fragarach in Irish Mythology?

Tags: ulster-cycle, weapons

Wikipedia has a short page on the truth-discerning sword [Fragarach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragarach), passed from Lugh to Cúchulainn, and subsequently to Conn Cétchathach.

It's been a while since I last read the the Ulster Cycle so I was wondering if anyone remembers offhand where this sword appears in the texts.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's Manannan's sword, [Lugh wears it](https://books.google.ca/books?id=y5MEAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA159&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the story of *The Fate of the Children of Tuireann*. He has Manannan's horse, lorica (breastplate) and his sword, probably because Manannan fostered him.

Two translations, one by [Eugene O'Curry](https://books.google.ca/books?id=y5MEAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA159&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) and another by [P.W. Joyce](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=c98YAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA51&hl=ja&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q=Answerer&f=false) both mention this, so presumably there's the source. (I found [these sources here](http://home.ix.netcom.com/~kiyoweap/myth/arms-weap/freagarthach.htm), by the way.) I didn't have much luck until I checked [James MacKillop](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780198609674.001.0001/acref-9780198609674)'s dictionary of Celtic mythology and discovered that the sword was called Frecraid as well as Fragarach. If you Google the latter you get more useful hits.

According to the book *[Myths and Legends of the Celts](https://books.google.ca/books?id=HI5yXNhbebYC&pg=PT188&lpg=PT188&dq=Frecraid%20Lugh&source=bl&ots=k6j2jAVt7a&sig=z6xQZkVW2qX8nBo9pA5_qbBP09I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix0Oq8xJbVAhUBaCYKHXS_CbQQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=Frecraid%20Lugh&f=false)*, Lugh got the sword in Tir na mBeo, the otherworld called the Land of the Living, but it doesn't give a source.